# Get last week and next week number from week number

Tags: sql, sql-server, week-number

I would like to get last week and next week number from week number.
How to get the next week number if it's December or the last week if it's January ?

I use ISO week numbers.
Desired results:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Clearly next week number for december will always be 1 and previous week number for january will always be 53

Comment: @AndyKorneyev your year has 53 weeks? :P Btw. January 1st 2017 and January 2nd 2017 was in week number 52.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, are you sure? ISO has one weeknumber definition, but many countries have their own versions.

Comment: @waka, According to ISO 2017-01-01 was in week 52, but 2017-01-02 was in week 1.

Comment: @jarlh Yes. That happens when you don't look carefully enough. My previous statement concerning January 2nd was wrong. :)

Comment: To find previous week number, subtract 1 date from weekstart and return that date's week number. To find next week number, add 7 days etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
select datepart(year,dateadd(day,-1,week_dt_start)) * 100 +
       datepart(week,dateadd(day,-1,week_dt_start)) as prev_week,
       datepart(year,dateadd(day,1,week_dt_end)) * 100 + 
       datepart(week,dateadd(day,1,week_dt_end)) as next_week
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh for your answer but it's not working. I have an error message: Msg 195, Niveau 15, État 10, Ligne 2
'week' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Too bad. When it comes to date/time too many products have their own way doing things... Well, wait a few seconds.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT, read my comment above and you'll understand. (I was also expecting OP to give more feedback...)